# CountDownTimer потребляет много памяти

Tags: java, android

В сервисе у меня есть таймер по окончанию которой идет запрос к серверу:

```
public void timerToConnect() {

        final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * TIME_TO_REQUEST, 1000 * 60 * TIME_TO_REQUEST_INTERVAL) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                getDataFromServer();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
```

Вот сам метод:

```
public void getDataFromServer() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (!response.isEmpty() && JSON_Utils.isJSONValid(response) && !response.trim().equals("\"error\"")) {

                        ReadData readData = new ReadData(response);

                        List<MainModel> mainList = readData.getMainModelList();

                    }

                    timerToConnect();
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("CONNECTION", "Ошибка при подключении к сети " + error);
                    getDataFromServer();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("tvid", GlobalData.getTvId(getApplicationContext()));

            return params;
        }
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);

}
```

В отладке показывает Таймер что много кушает. Мне еще кажется что нужно очищать и Volley. Хотя не знаю как. Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы таймер не потреблял много память в сервисе, так как он каждые 5 минут делает запрос

Comment: Скорее всего вы какой-то ресурс не освобождаете, что за класс `ReadData`?

Comment: Это класс, где делаю парсинг json ответа

Comment: стоп, стоп, я правильно понял, что у вас где-то вызывается `timerToConnect`, в котором внутри вызывается `getDataFromServer` в котором внутри вызывается `timerToConnect, в котором внутри...?

Comment: Сперва вызывается `getDataFromServer` > после парсинга данных обратно > `timerToConnect` чтобы таймер обратно заработал и после окончания таймера обратно  `getDataFromServer` и так далее...